# CSS error in "Here's how it works" banner, extraneous images are included

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There's a CSS issue that's causing parts of other sprites to appear below the correct images, especially beneath the "Anybody can ask a question" text, in the "Here's how it works" banner for users not logged in:

[image: CSS bug in "Here's how it works" banner]

(The above image is from a Nexus 9 running CyanogenMod 12, but the issue reproduces on any device running a modern browser.)

The issue affects the Trilogy and a few other sites which share the same CSS. Can someone look into it?

Comment: Wow, this wasn't obvious to me. The fact that the questions were less than an hour apart sadly did not help as the title of the other question wasn't quite descriptive ("graphics crop" didn't quite mean "extraneous parts of images" to me).

Comment: Yeah, that title is weird. Either way, the issue is fixed. :)